# Can Android Instant Apps be integrated with Hybrid app?

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, android-instant-apps

The Android Instant Apps is a new thing, and I just wanted to know if it can be integrated with the Hybrid app structure (HTML/JS with Cordova wrapper).

I'm not a native app developer so I'm not sure of this myself.

Answer (score 1):

According to Googlers ,well main idea behind instant app is

> To make the native app experience as convenient as surfing to a web
>   site. “Web pages are ephemeral,They appear, you use them, and never
>   think about them again.” Apps, have lots of friction and
>   often you only want an app to perform one action or to get a specific
>   piece of information.

Google's examples of Instant Apps included museum or resort apps with maps and schedules, along with apps that help you pay for parking. These are the kinds of rarely-used apps that are useful in the moment, though you wouldn't necessarily want to install them on your phone beforehand or keep them around afterward. Developers can, however, can provide "call to action" links that encourage users to download and install apps that they find particularly useful.

Instant Apps are a logical evolution of App Links, a Marshmallow-era feature that lets installed apps designate themselves as the default options for opening certain kinds of links. For instance, clicking a link to Pinterest might open up the Pinterest app rather than Pinterest's mobile site—Apple's "Universal Links" in iOS 9 provide similar functionality.

**Google requires apps that use App Links to prove that they're associated with the sites they say they're associated with; the exact same sort of verification will be used for Instant Apps.**

So if we analyze all the information provided by googlers Instant Apps for a start is only for native apps there is no scope for Hybrid Apps...

Hope this make sense...I am able to clear your doubt..we will know more when..the exact availability of instant apps for both end users and developers will gradually expand access to feature and bring it to users...

Comment: if only google made it possible for instant apps to show up in IOS devices!! that would've been great and at the same time the end of mobile ridiculous web pages!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, I don't see why not as Instant Apps end up compiling to what is just a regular APK (or set of APKs).

Will it work out-of-the-box? I doubt it, as there may be issues with tooling (which is via Android Studio) as well as runtime issues (Instant Apps have some restrictions on what they can do, see the [FAQ](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html)).

Is it recommended? Probably not, as the point of Instant Apps is to provide a fast, native app experience. If the hybrid app ultimately loads HTML/JS then there is likely minimal advantage over simply loading an optimized mobile website.